Different approaches to present Financial Accessibility assumption
I am trying to develop the article "Arbitrage and Equilibrium with Portfolio Constraints" (http://www.workshop2011.unsl.edu.ar/Trabajos/Cornet/2009_ET_DOI_cornet-gopalan.pdf section 3.3). However I am not able to find some proof of the below $\text{sets of implications: } [FA1 \Rightarrow FA2 \Rightarrow FA3 \Rightarrow FA], \text{ and } [FA2' \Rightarrow FA]$.
$FA: \text{ The closed cone spanned by } \bigcup_{i \in I} W(\bar{q}) (Z_i) \text{ is a linear space.}$
$FA1: \exists i_0 \in \mathcal{I} \text{ such that } Z_{i_0} = \mathbb{R}^J.$
$FA2: \text{for some } i_0 \in \mathcal{I}, Z_{i_0} \text{ is a linear space and for all } i \in \mathcal{I}, Z_i \subset Z_{i_0}.$
$FA2': \text{ there exists } i \in \mathcal{I} \text{ such that } 0 \in \text{int } Z_i.$
$FA3: \text{the cone spanned by } \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} W(\bar{q})Z_i \text{ is equal to } \text{Im } W(\bar{q}).$
Where
$
\mathcal{J} = \{1, \ldots, J\} \text{ - the set of assets}
$
For every consumer $i \in I = \{1, \ldots, I\}$ - set of agents , we denote by $z_i = (z_j^i)_{j \in \mathcal{J}} \in \mathbb{R}^J$ the portfolio of agent i.
$
Z_i \subset \mathbb{R}^J, \text{ which represents the set of portfolios that are admissible for agent } i.
$
Formally, we denote by $V^j_\xi $ the payoff of asset at node $ \xi \in D $, and by $ V^j = (V^j_\xi)_{\xi \in D} \in \mathbb{R}^D $ its payoff across all nodes.
The full payoff matrix  W(q)  is the $(D \times J) $-matrix with entries
$$
W^j_\xi(q) := V^j_\xi - \delta_{\xi, \xi(j)} q_j,
$$
where $ \delta_{\xi, \xi'} = 1 $ if $ \xi = \xi' $ and $ \delta_{\xi, \xi'} = 0 $ otherwise.
